# Different dependencies for azure-storage-blob in spring boot apps

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have two different **Spring Boot** projects using `same azure-storage-blob` dependency.

When I run the maven commmand given below:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

I see two different dependencies for `azure-storage-blob`.

For First app:

```
+- com.azure:azure-storage-blob:jar:12.23.0:compile
|  |  |  +- com.azure:azure-core:jar:1.41.0:compile
|  |  |  |  \- com.azure:azure-json:jar:1.0.1:compile
|  |  |  +- com.azure:azure-core-http-netty:jar:1.13.5:compile
|  |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.59.Final:compile
|  |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.59.Final:compile
|  |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-kqueue:jar:osx-x86_64:4.1.59.Final:compile
|  |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:2.0.36.Final:compile
|  |  |  |  \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http:jar:1.0.33:compile
|  |  |  |     +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns:jar:4.1.59.Final:compile
|  |  |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-dns:jar:4.1.59.Final:compile
|  |  |  |     +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos:jar:osx-x86_64:4.1.59.Final:compile
|  |  |  |     \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-core:jar:1.0.33:compile
|  |  |  +- com.azure:azure-storage-common:jar:12.22.0:compile
|  |  |  \- com.azure:azure-storage-internal-avro:jar:12.8.0:compile
|  |  +- com.azure:azure-identity:jar:1.9.2:compile
|  |  |  +- com.microsoft.azure:msal4j:jar:1.13.8:compile
|  |  |  \- com.microsoft.azure:msal4j-persistence-extension:jar:1.2.0:compile
|  |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.59.Final:compileenter code here
```

For Second app :

```
+- com.azure:azure-storage-blob:jar:12.23.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.azure:azure-core:jar:1.41.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.azure:azure-json:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.13.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.13.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.13.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.4.32:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.azure:azure-core-http-netty:jar:1.13.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.97.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.97.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.97.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.97.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.97.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.97.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.97.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.97.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.97.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.97.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.97.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-classes-epoll:jar:4.1.97.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-kqueue:jar:osx-x86_64:4.1.97.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-classes-kqueue:jar:4.1.97.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:2.0.61.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-classes:jar:2.0.61.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:linux-x86_64:2.0.61.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:linux-aarch_64:2.0.61.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:osx-x86_64:2.0.61.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:osx-aarch_64:2.0.61.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:windows-x86_64:2.0.61.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http:jar:1.0.35:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns:jar:4.1.97.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-dns:jar:4.1.97.Final:compile
```

Although both of the apps uses the same dependency from `azure-storage-blob` with version `12.23.0` but it can be seen from the output that azure-storage-blob has different dependencies of different versions.

> io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.97.Final

in the second app and

> io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.59.Final

in the first app

What caused such a difference and how to find which dependency actually brought these different dependencies?

Thanks in advance.

UPD:In pom.xml of the first app ( problematic ) there are following definitions :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
    <version>12.23.0</version>
    <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-resolver</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Netty -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.97.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-handler-proxy</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.97.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-buffer</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.97.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-codec-http</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.97.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-resolver</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.97.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Tried to exclude netty-resolver dependency from azure-storage-blob dependency + added explicit import by version of netty-resolver , but still version 4.1.59 was imported .
Is here also important order ? Thanks

Exception :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/netty/http/client/HttpClient

    at com.azure.core.http.netty.NettyAsyncHttpClientBuilder.build(NettyAsyncHttpClientBuilder.java:154)
    at com.azure.core.http.netty.NettyAsyncHttpClientProvider.createInstance(NettyAsyncHttpClientProvider.java:56)
    at com.azure.core.http.netty.NettyAsyncHttpClientProvider.createInstance(NettyAsyncHttpClientProvider.java:62)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.http.HttpClientProviders.lambda$createInstance$0(HttpClientProviders.java:46)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.util.Providers.create(Providers.java:114)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.http.HttpClientProviders.createInstance(HttpClientProviders.java:46)
    at com.azure.core.http.HttpClient.createDefault(HttpClient.java:61)
    at com.azure.core.http.HttpClient.createDefault(HttpClient.java:51)
    at com.azure.core.http.HttpPipelineBuilder.build(HttpPipelineBuilder.java:78)
    at com.azure.storage.blob.implementation.util.BuilderHelper.buildPipeline(BuilderHelper
```

UPD3: part of pom.xml - of second app - working :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
    <artifactId>oauth2-oidc-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>6.15</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-storage</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
    <version>12.23.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Additional difference : for first app  ( problematic ) was added Azure functionality to existing code . The second app ( Working) was generated by Spring Initializr and added azure imports

Answer (score 1):

It's clearly there in the logs that you have shared.

`io.netty:netty-resolver-dns:jar:4.1.97.Final` is coming from `io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http:jar:1.0.35` in your second app.

whereas

`io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.59.Final` is coming from `com.azure:azure-storage-blob:jar:12.23.0` in your first app

Basically, the second app's omitted the use of `io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.59.Final` that was coming from `com.azure:azure-storage-blob:jar:12.23.0` instead it selected the one coming from `reactor-netty-http` because it was using the latest version of `netty-resolver-dns (4.1.97.Final)`.

To be short, newer/higher versions are given priority by Maven if multiple same dependencies are found.

Comment: Thanks for reply . IN pom.xml of the first app ( problematic ) , I have following dependencies

Comment: @lm. Please edit the question to add more details.

Comment: editted - added part of pom.xml definition

Comment: @lm. Can you share the codebase?

Comment: added problematic code fragment

Comment: @lm. Can you add the pom of second app?

Comment: @lm. Remove the code and keep the exception part only.

Comment: added part of pom.xml from second app (working)

Comment: @lm. Can you do mvn clean install on the first project/

Comment: @lm. You first pom is working. It's showing me that maven has picked netty-resolver-4.19.7.

Comment: After recheck - the issue occurs when first app imported as jar by other. I will try to reproduce with sample app the issue .